# $_SERVER['document_root'] returns /htdocs not /public_html

Tags: php, hosting

I'm looking to switch over to a new host, and they provide this nice little "temporary url" to test out your files before you switch.  All fine and dandy.  So I copy over all of my files.  At the top of every page I `require` another file from the server that is stored at `public_html/includes/head.php`.  Now for whatever reason, the $_SERVER['document_root'] var is returning /public_html/htdocs/includes/head.php (which does not exist on the server) and not /public_html/includes/head.php (which does exist).  The resulting error is as follows:

```
Warning: require_once(/home/secure31/public_html/htdocs/includes/head.php) 
[function.require-once]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in 
/home/stephe80/public_html/index.php on line 6
```

The guilty code:

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/head.php');
```

I am inclined to think that this is an error associated with their temporary url setup, but I do not want to transfer over my DNS and find that all of my files are broken.  I could change them to absolute paths, but I am curious as to whether I am missing something.  Any insight would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is based on the calling file's location. Have you tried looking at the value of `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` and `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` for the calling file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference (if anyone has similar issues), it turns out that the problem was with their test server.  I launched it with my code as-was (risky, I know), and all turned out well.

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest to use the [`__FILE__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) constant and work out your htdocs folder from there. It's much more reliable than relying on the $_SERVER superglobal, since that actually differs from server to server.

Example (that you'd call in your index.php in root folder):

```
$htdocs = str_replace(basename(__FILE__), __FILE__, '');
define('ROOT_FOLDER', $htdocs);
require_once(ROOT_FOLDER . '/includes/head.php');
```

Comment: `__DIR__` is way better for this one.

Comment: @Marwelln nice one, I didn't know they added that... it's 5.3+ though, so not usable in all environments

Comment: Thanks, ZathrusWriter and @Marwelln for the response.  This does seem to be a more consistent method, and I will certainly look into implementing it.  Turns out the problem was with their test server (as I thought).